# Como faço para exibir o JSON da API?

Tags: javascript, json, api

Após realizar a execução deste, me deparei com esse erro, o qual não exibi as informações da API. Sendo que em uma outra URL de uma API semelhante o código exibia e funcionava perfeitamente.

URL da API: https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all

```js
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 dataType: "JSON",
 url: "https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all",
 success: function(data){
  console.log(data["USD"]["code"]);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o erro? E transcreva o código, [edit] a pergunta e não mostre uma imagem, isso dificulta a ajuda ao seu problema.

Comment: Faz um teste com GET ao invés de POST

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado Caique Romero!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está recebendo um erro com o código HTTP 405. Este código de erro tem como descrição:

> Método não permitido

Ou seja, você está fazendo a requisição para um recurso válido, porém com um método que o servidor não pode responder.

Abrindo a URL pelo navegador eu consegui visualizar a resposta, isso quer dizer que o recurso aceita requisições GET.

Então é só mudar o `type` da requisição.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "JSON",
  url: "https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data["USD"]["code"]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara, se entendi bem vc deve estar querendo visualizar os dados retornados na API correto?

Você pode usar o console.log(data) para visualizar. 
E para acessar cada atributo dos objetos vc pode usar objeto.atributo. Nesse caso como o response é um list vc pode utilizar o laço for. Por exemplo:

```
       $.ajax({
            url:'https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all',
            method:'get',
            success:function(data){
                for(var i in data){
                    console.log(data[i].code);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, eu sempre uso `JSON.stringify()` dentro de um `console.log()` pra mostrar o resultado de uma chamada ajax que retorna um json. Ficaria assim:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "JSON",
   url: "https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all",
   success: function(data){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
});
```

Pois dessa forma você consegue visualizar todo o conteúdo e estrutura do JSON pra conseguir trabalhar com ele.